# Time dependent data in Mayavi

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array, mayavi

Assuming I have a 4d numpy array like this: `my_array[x,y,z,t]`.

Is there a simple way to load the whole array into Mayavi, and simply selecting the `t` I want to investigate for?

I know that it is possible to animate the data, but I would like to rotate my figure "on the go".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to set up a dialogue with a input box in which you can set `t`.
You have to use the traits.api, it could look like this:

```
from traits.api import HasTraits, Int, Instance, on_trait_change
from traitsui.api import View, Item, Group
from mayavi.core.ui.api import SceneEditor, MlabSceneModel, MayaviScene

class Data_plot(HasTraits):
  a = my_array
  t = Int(0)
  scene = Instance(MlabSceneModel, ())
  plot = Instance(PipelineBase)

  @on_trait_change('scene.activated')
  def show_plot(self):
    self.plot = something(self.a[self.t]) #something can be surf or mesh or other

  @on_trait_change('t')
  def update_plot(self):
    self.plot.parent.parent.scalar_data = self.a[self.t] #Change the data

  view = View(Item('scene', editor=SceneEditor(scene_class=MayaviScene),
                show_label=False),
                Group('_', 't'),
                resizable=True,
                )

my_plot = Data_plot(a=my_array)
my_plot.configure_traits()
```

You can also set up a slider with the command `Range` instead of `Int` if you prefer this.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Could you elaborate your code a bit? As far as I can see, `t = Int(0)` returns a traits object, which makes it impossible to use to slice the numpy array called `a`.
Also: `self.a` seems not to be a possible call, but rather `a` in `self.plot = something(self.a[t])`. It would also be nice with an example of the `something()` function.

Comment: I changed the code a little. The something function can be any plot module you like, for example surf() or mesh(). The example code I've provided is not generally working, you have to adjust it to your needs, it should just give you an idea of how to solve your problem, because your question is quite general.

Comment: The changes to the code helps :). However, by adding `from mayavi.mlab import mesh` and changing the function from `something` to `mesh` will result in an empty plot at first, followed by `TypeError: grid_source() takes exactly 3 arguments (1 given)
` upon start and `AttributeError: 'Data_plot' object has no attribute 'plot'` upon change of t. I agree with you that the answer should be quite general, but having a example working out of the box (that could easily be altered) would be nice :).

Comment: I've used a similar code to plot a image plane widget and update it, for mesh() the data update should work with the .set or .reset command.

Comment: Also for mesh you need x,y,z coordinates as 2d arrays, so you need to choose the part of your array that fits. Look it up here: [link](http://docs.enthought.com/mayavi/mayavi/auto/mlab_helper_functions.html)